# SQL XML dd/mm/yyyy failing to return as string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a legacy system that only accepts dd/mm/yyyy in the XML for the data fields otherwise it mucks up the data entry.

I have tried every which way to attempt to force my data fields to display as dd/mm/yyyy, I have attempted to CONVERT to DATETIME 103, I have tried declaring it as a VARCHAR and everytime time it returns as 2018-05-11 for example.

How can I force the returned field to display as DD/MM/YYYY, this is a snippet of my code, excuse how messy it is unfortunately it is very linear and the system that accepts the XML is very basic.

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 'job/queue',
       @Branch 'job/branch',
       CASE WHEN myli.PolRef@ IS NOT NULL THEN 'update-broomsrisk' ELSE 'create-broomsrisk' END 'parameters/yzt/char20.1',
       SUBSTRING(@PolicyRef,1,6) 'broomsdata/broomsclient/bcm/refno',
       @PolicyRef 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/bpy/refno',
       CASE WHEN myli.PolRef@ IS NOT NULL THEN myli.key@ ELSE NULL END 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/KEY',
       (SELECT ISNULL(ct2.convictiondate,ct2.offencedate) FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 1) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date1',
       (SELECT ct2.code FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 1) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code1',
       (SELECT ct2.fine FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 1) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine1',
       (SELECT ct2.noofpoints FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 1) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points1',
       (SELECT ISNULL(ct2.convictiondate,ct2.offencedate) FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 2) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date2',
       (SELECT ct2.code FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 2) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code2',
       (SELECT ct2.fine FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 2) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine2',
       (SELECT ct2.noofpoints FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 2) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points2',
       (SELECT ISNULL(ct2.convictiondate,ct2.offencedate) FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 3) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date3',
       (SELECT ct2.code FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 3) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code3',
       (SELECT ct2.fine FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 3) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine3',
       (SELECT ct2.noofpoints FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 3) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points3',
       (SELECT ISNULL(ct2.convictiondate,ct2.offencedate) FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 4) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date4',
       (SELECT ct2.code FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 4) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code4',
       (SELECT ct2.fine FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 4) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine4',
       (SELECT ct2.noofpoints FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 4) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points4'
FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct
LEFT OUTER JOIN [FIG-SQL-SRV].InfoCentre.dbo.ic_BD_MYLI AS myli ON ct.branch = myli.B@ AND ct.policyRef = myli.PolRef@
FOR XML PATH('xmlexecute'), TYPE;
```

The Fields I'm trying to force are the 'Date1'/'Date2' etc. fields.

Cheers

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Holy subquery overload batman. You do not need a subquery from the same table over and over like this. Some conditional aggregation would solve this much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONVERT(varchar(10), YourDateColumn, 103)`. I think your mistake was trying to convert to a datetime (I'm guessing you tried `CONVERT(datetime, YourDateColumn, 103)`) while using a style code; date/time datatypes, in SQL Server, have no format. Trying to format them won't do anything.

For example: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103);` returns the `varchar(10)` value `'11/05/2018'`.

Edit: The below is to (temporary) assist the OP in showing how i create XML for OpenInterchange. The OP is using a lot of Sub Selects, something that doesn't help the speed of the query. I've highlighted, a couple of points for the OP to note as well:

```
SELECT K.Insco AS Insurer,
       K.B@ AS Branch,
       K.PolRef@ AS PolicyRef,
       K.ClaimRef@ AS ClaimRef,
       --XML Generation starts here.
       (SELECT(SELECT K.B@ AS branch,
               'OO' AS operator,
               'PDF' AS printtype
               FOR XML PATH('job'),TYPE),
              (SELECT (SELECT 'update-claim' AS [Char20.1]
                       FOR XML PATH('yzt'),TYPE)
               FOR XML PATH('parameters'),TYPE),
              (SELECT (SELECT (SELECT K.Ref@ AS Refno
                               FOR XML PATH('bcm'),TYPE)
                       FOR XML PATH('broomsclient'),TYPE),
                       (SELECT (SELECT K.PolRef@ AS Refno
                               FOR XML PATH('bpy'),TYPE)
                       FOR XML PATH('broomspolicy'),TYPE),
                       (SELECT (SELECT K.ClaimRef@ AS [Claim.No],
                                       K.[Claim No] AS [Ins.Claim.Ref],
                                       K.KGMSettled AS [Claim.Settled],
                                       K.KGMReserve AS [Claim.Reserve],
                                       K.KGMReserve + K.KGMSettled As [Claim.Amount],
                                       K.KGMStatus AS [Stat.Desc],
                                       CASE K.KGMStatus WHEN 'Settled' THEN 'SETT'
                                                        WHEN 'Ouststanding' THEN 'OUTS'
                                                        WHEN 'Declined' THEN 'DECL'
                                                        WHEN 'Not Taken up' THEN 'NTUP'
                                                        WHEN 'Withdrawn' THEN 'WITH' END AS [stat.code],
                                       CONVERT(varchar(10),K.[Notified Date],103) AS [Date.repd], --First example of the dd/MM/yyyy format
                                       CONVERT(varchar(10),K.[Loss Date],103) AS [Loss.date], --Another example of the dd/MM/yyyy format
                                       CASE WHEN K.[Date Closed] IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) END AS [Stat.date], -- and another example of the dd/MM/yyyy format
                                       CONVERT(varchar(10),K.[Date Closed],103) AS [Date.Settled], --you get the idea. :)
                                       CASE WHEN K.[Date Closed] IS NOT NULL AND K.[Incident Type] = 'Windscreen' THEN 'Yes'
                                            WHEN K.[Date Closed] IS NULL THEN ''
                                            WHEN K.[NCB Decision] = 'Allowed' THEN 'Yes'
                                            WHEN K.[NCB Decision] = 'Disallowed' THEN 'Yes' END AS [Settled.free]
                                       /*
                                       CASE WHEN K.[Date Closed] IS NOT NULL AND K.[Incident Type] = 'Windscreen' THEN 'Yes'
                                            WHEN K.KGMReserve + K.KGMSettled = 0 AND K.[Date Closed] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
                                            WHEN K.KGMReserve + K.KGMSettled > 0 AND K.[Date Closed] IS NOT NULL THEN 'No'
                                            ELSE '' END AS [Settled.free]*/
                                FOR XML PATH('bch'),TYPE),
                               (SELECT K.BCAKey AS [KEY],
                                       K.[Vehicle Reg# No] AS [Reg.no],
                                       K.[Driver Name] AS [Driver],
                                       K.[ AD Paid] AS [Pay.ad],
                                       K.[AD Reserve] AS [Reserve.ad],
                                       K.[TPD Paid] + K.[TPI Paid] AS [Pay.tp],
                                       K.[TPD Reserve] + K.[TPI Reserve] AS [Reserve.tp],
                                       --K.[TPI Paid] AS [Pay.others],
                                       --K.[TPI Reserve] AS [Reserve.others],
                                       0 AS [Pay.others],
                                       0 AS [Reserve.others],
                                       K.KGMSettled AS [Pay.total],
                                       K.KGMReserve AS [Reserve.Total],
                                       K.[Recovery] AS [Pay.recovs],
                                       K.[AD Recovery Reserve] AS [Reserve.recovs],
                                       'Updated by FileDrop Service. XML Generated on ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),103) as [Remarks4]
                                FOR XML PATH('bca'),TYPE),
                               (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),103) AS [date],
                                       LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),108),5) AS [time],
                                       'OO' AS [op],
                                       'FileDrop' AS [Name],
                                       K.KGMSettled AS [Settled],
                                       K.KGMReserve AS [Reserve],
                                       K.KGMSettled + K.KGMReserve As [Total],
                                       --CONVERT(varchar(10),K.DataToDate,103) AS [EffDate],
                                       CASE WHEN K.KGMSettled != K.BCHSettled THEN 'Payment'
                                            WHEN K.KGMReserve != K.BCHReserve THEN 'Reserve Adjustment'
                                            ELSE 'Payment' END AS [Notes]
                                FOR XML PATH('clam'),TYPE)
                        FOR XML PATH('broomsclaim'),TYPE)
               FOR XML PATH('broomsdata'),TYPE)
        FOR XML PATH('xmlexecute'),TYPE) AS InputXML,
        GETDATE() AS DateGenerated,
        0 AS TestLoad
FROM KGMCGStandard_viw K
WHERE K.ClaimsFound = 1 
  AND K.KGMFound = 1
  AND (K.KGMSettled != K.BCHSettled
   OR  K.KGMReserve != K.BCHReserve
   OR  (CONVERT(date,K.KGMClosure) != CONVERT(date,BCHClosure)
   OR   (K.KGMClosure IS NULL AND K.BCHClosure IS NOT NULL)
   OR   (K.KGMClosure IS NOT NULL AND K.BCHClosure IS NULL))
   OR (CASE WHEN K.[Date Closed] IS NOT NULL AND K.[Incident Type] = 'Windscreen' THEN 'Yes'
                                             WHEN K.[NCB Decision] = 'Allowed' THEN 'Yes'
                                             WHEN K.[NCB Decision] = 'Disallowed' THEN 'No' END != K.Settled_Free
   OR  (K.[Date Closed] IS NULL AND K.Settled_free IS NULL)))
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM AutoloadXML_tbl A
                  WHERE A.Branch = K.B@
                    AND A.PolicyRef = K.PolRef@
                    AND A.ClaimRef = K.ClaimRef@
                    AND (A.DateSubmitted IS NULL 
                     OR  A.Installed = 0))
ORDER BY K.ClaimRef@ ASC;
```

Comment: Hi Larnu, when piped out to the XML it still returns yyyy-mm-dd. <myli>
        <Date1>2015-06-05</Date1>

Comment: @Lynchie It really doesn't. I literally use that SQL everyday (not joking, I have to feed 100's of Insurance claim details into a system via XML, and i have to use the format `dd/MM/yyyy` for every date value). Try `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS DateValue
FOR XML PATH('Root');`. The return value is `<Root><DateValue>11/05/2018</DateValue></Root>`

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(SELECT ISNULL(ct2.convictiondate,ct2.offencedate) FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 1),103) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date1', still returns 2015-06-05 instead of 05/06/2015.

Comment: Sounds like you have an implicit conversion else where; so the `varchar` value is being cast back to a `date`. This is clearly for OpenGI's Open Interchange, which is what I use the above SQL for; i know it works. :)

Comment: Haha - Top man you would be correct :) I've never come across the issue before, usually everything imports perfectly fine - just appears to be this frame and these data fields.

Comment: @Lynchie gimme a bit of time to reformat your SQL. There's no need for so many subselects when generating XML for OpenInterchange; it'll be really bad for performance. I'll, however, post an example of something I've done previously that might help you though. notice how i nest the different frames i need (this is actually going to the Claims side of things, but the idea is identical).

Comment: @Lynchie (this won't be a quick change btw, you'll need to give me a couple of hours, as I've got a lunch break to go to :) )

Comment: Sussed it, it wasn't treating the returned information as a date. CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CAST((SELECT ISNULL(ct2.convictiondate,ct2.offencedate) FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct2 WHERE ct2.RowNo = 1) AS DATE),103) 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date1',

Comment: Glad to see you worked it out. I had, assumed, that your date was stored already as a date ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already figured out the date part I will leave that up to you but your query could be simplified majorly using conditional aggregation. I used square braces around the column names instead of single quotes. Sure those work but I consider that a bad habit because it is difficult to decide if it is a string literal or a column alias. I also prefer to use alias = but that is more a preference thing. I also prefer leading commas which is also a preference thing.

Pretty sure this query should do the same thing.

```
SELECT 1 as 'job/queue',
       @Branch as 'job/branch',
       CASE WHEN myli.PolRef@ IS NOT NULL THEN 'update-broomsrisk' ELSE 'create-broomsrisk' END as 'parameters/yzt/char20.1',
       SUBSTRING(@PolicyRef,1,6) as 'broomsdata/broomsclient/bcm/refno',
       @PolicyRef as 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/bpy/refno',
       CASE WHEN myli.PolRef@ IS NOT NULL THEN myli.key@ ELSE NULL END as 'broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/KEY'
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date1] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 1 then ISNULL(ct.convictiondate, ct.offencedate) end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code1] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 1 then ct.code end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine1] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 1 then ct.fine end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points1] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 1 then ct.noofpoints end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date2] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 2 then ISNULL(ct.convictiondate, ct.offencedate) end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code2] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 2 then ct.code end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine2] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 2 then ct.fine end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 2 then ct.noofpoints end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date3] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 3 then ISNULL(ct.convictiondate, ct.offencedate) end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code3] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 3 then ct.code end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine3] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 3 then ct.fine end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points3] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 3 then ct.noofpoints end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Date4] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 4 then ISNULL(ct.convictiondate, ct.offencedate) end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Code4] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 4 then ct.code end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Fine4] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 4 then ct.fine end)
       , [broomsdata/broomspolicy/myli/Points4] = max(case when ct.RowNo = 4 then ct.noofpoints end)
FROM #ConvictionTable AS ct
LEFT OUTER JOIN [FIG-SQL-SRV].InfoCentre.dbo.ic_BD_MYLI AS myli ON ct.branch = myli.B@ AND ct.policyRef = myli.PolRef@
GROUP BY @Branch
    , CASE WHEN myli.PolRef@ IS NOT NULL THEN 'update-broomsrisk' ELSE 'create-broomsrisk' END
    , SUBSTRING(@PolicyRef,1,6)
    , @PolicyRef
    , CASE WHEN myli.PolRef@ IS NOT NULL THEN myli.key@ ELSE NULL END
FOR XML PATH('xmlexecute'), TYPE
```